# using correct syntax in pymysql for passing python variable to query

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I   am  trying to pass  a  a  variable   x   which is a  string to a  python query   to get output. I am  using pymysql .However, when I   run it I get  error:

Note: I have  commented out import  of  x     for time being, its  actually username   entered  at login page   by the  user

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
#from Roster import x
x='bh16'
IT = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xxx.xx.xx', user='xxxx', password='xxxx',
         db='xxxx')#Connect  to the IT database
Others = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xx.xx.x0', user='xxxxxxx', password='xxxx',
         db='samsdb')#Connect to the non IT database
a=IT.cursor() # Open Cursor for IT  database
b=Others.cursor()#Open Cursor for non-IT  database
m='''(select  verticalorg from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=%s,(x))'''
a.execute(m)
b.execute(m)
c=a.fetchall()
d=b.fetchall()
q=c+d
print(q)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql-0.7.9-py3.5.egg\pymysql\connections.py", line 981, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql-0.7.9-py3.5.egg\pymysql\connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pymysql-0.7.9-py3.5.egg\pymysql\err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s,(x))' at line 1")
```

Comment: `,(x)` is not supposed to be part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

This  works

```
sql="select verticalorg from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=(%s)"
args=x
a.execute(sql,args)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in python 3.4 and above

```
import pymysql
#from Roster import x
x='bh16'
IT = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xxx.xx.xx', user='xxxx', password='xxxx',
         db='xxxx')#Connect  to the IT database
Others = pymysql.connect(host='xx.xx.xx.x0', user='xxxxxxx', password='xxxx', db='samsdb')#Connect to the non IT database
a=IT.cursor() # Open Cursor for IT  database
b=Others.cursor()#Open Cursor for non-IT  database
m= ("select  verticalorg from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=%s" %x)
a.execute(m)
b.execute(m)
c=a.fetchall()
d=b.fetchall()
print(c)
```